# How to associate an api token with a user account

Tags: rest, security, authorization

So, I created a little note taking app which is secured by JWTs (The user logs in, receives a token which is then used to authenticate the user on every request to the api)

In order to allow access to external applications I was playing around with the concept of API-tokens, similarly how, for example, gitlab does it.

If you have a gitlab account, you can generate a secret token. With that token in hand external applications can now perform operations on the gitlab api.

I think that I understood the basic concept so far

I implemented the functionality which allows a user to generate a token. A hash is generated for that token and stored in the database. The (unhashed) token is then returned to the user.

Now comes the part, that gives me some pretty headaches:

Since the token does not contain any account information (it is just a random string) how can the endpoint checking the api-token associate that token to an account?

Sure, I could simply iterate over all stored api tokens of every account and take the first match (remember that I hashed the token which means that i can not make a simple lookup). But I wouldn't feel very comfortable with that approach.

The second idea that came to me was to just use a jwt as api token packed with user information. The token gets, imo, a bit too long and I'm not sure if that would expose too much information for that use case and hence be security issue.

I feel that I'm missing a detail here and hope that someone can lead me into the right direction.

Comment: If the hash in the DB does not include any kind of salt/pepper (and it should not because there is simply no reason to) then simply hash the incoming token and us this to do the lookup. Or did I misunderstood your point?

Comment: Interesting point. Why should the hash not be salted? Are API-tokens not supposed to be treated like passwords?

Comment: API tokens are nothing like passwords. Passwords are considered to have low entropy, API tokens are supposed to have high entropy. We use salt to get different hashes for passwords where the probability of duplicates is relatively high. We don't need salt for API keys, because the probability of duplicates is negligible.